# I tried to calculate the hashCode for some String but failed, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, oop

I know that algorithm for a String hashCode is

```
s[0]*31^(n - 1) + s[1]*31^(n - 2) + ... + s[n - 1]
```

I tried to calculate on calculator what hashCode would If I have a String like this

```
String s = new String("blue");
```

Using the algorithm (for conversion from char to int I used ASCII converter) I have:
98*31^(3) + 108*31^2 + 117*31 + 101 + 98 + 108 + 117 +101 = **3027458**

But when I type:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String("blue");

        System.out.println(s.hashCode());
    }
```

I get output: **3027034**

What am I doing wrong? Why the hashCode is not like it's supposed to be according to the algorithm?

Comment: Where did you get `+ 98 + 108 + 117 +101` from?

Comment: Why does your equation have 8 terms?  There should be only 4 terms (one per character): `98*31^3 + 108*31^2 + 117*31^1 + 101`.  That extra `+ 98 + 108 + 117 + 101` is what's giving your the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misreading the formula.  Try doing this:

> 98*(31^3) + 108*(31^2) + 117*(31^1) + 101*(31^0)

This will output:

> 3027034

The extra additions at the end that you have are not part of the formula.

`s[n-1]` is used to show that the pattern of the formula continues for the entire `String`.

I added the `31^1` and `31^0` back into the complete formula to show clearly how it exactly is being calculated.  Note that `101*(31^0)` is just `101*1` which can be written `s[n-1]` for the final value.